# How to fix "[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: kube-master"

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, ansible

I'm trying to install Kubernetes on Google Cloud Instance using ansible, and it says it can't find the match over and over again,,

when I run `ansible-playbook -i inventory/mycluster/inventory.ini -v --become --become-user=root cluster.yml` :

```
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: kube-master

PLAY [Add kube-master nodes to kube_control_plane] ***********************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: kube-node

PLAY [Add kube-node nodes to kube_node] **********************************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: k8s-cluster
```

My `inventory.ini` :

```
[all]
instance-1 ansible_ssh_host=10.182.0.2 ip = 34.125.199.45 etcd_member_name=etcd1
instance-2 ansible_ssh_host=10.182.0.3 ip = 34.125.217.86 etcd_member_name=etcd2
instance-3 ansible_ssh_host=10.182.0.4 ip = 34.125.112.124 etcd_member_name=etcd3
instance-4 ansible_ssh_host=10.182.0.5 ip = 34.125.251.168
instance-5 ansible_ssh_host=10.182.0.6 ip = 34.125.231.40

# ## configure a bastion host if your nodes are not directly reachable
# bastion ansible_host=x.x.x.x ansible_user=some_user

[kube-master]
instance-1
instance-2
instance-3

[etcd]
instance-1
instance-2
instance-3

[kube-node]
instance-4
instance-5

[calico-rr]

[k8s-cluster:children]
kube-master
kube-node
calico-rr
```

My cluster.yml :

```
---
- name: Check ansible version
  import_playbook: ansible_version.yml

- name: Ensure compatibility with old groups
  import_playbook: legacy_groups.yml

- hosts: bastion[0]
  gather_facts: False
  environment: "{{ proxy_disable_env }}"
  roles:
    - { role: kubespray-defaults }
    - { role: bastion-ssh-config, tags: ["localhost", "bastion"] }

- hosts: k8s_cluster:etcd
  strategy: linear
  any_errors_fatal: "{{ any_errors_fatal | default(true) }}"
  gather_facts: false
  environment: "{{ proxy_disable_env }}"
  roles:
    - { role: kubespray-defaults }
    - { role: bootstrap-os, tags: bootstrap-os}

- name: Gather facts
  tags: always
  import_playbook: facts.yml

- hosts: k8s_cluster:etcd
  gather_facts: False
  any_errors_fatal: "{{ any_errors_fatal | default(true) }}"
  environment: "{{ proxy_disable_env }}"
  roles:
    - { role: kubespray-defaults }
    - { role: kubernetes/preinstall, tags: preinstall }
    - { role: "container-engine", tags: "container-engine", when: deploy_container_engine|default(true) }
    - { role: download, tags: download, when: "not skip_downloads" }


- hosts: k8s_cluster
  gather_facts: False
  any_errors_fatal: "{{ any_errors_fatal | default(true) }}"
```

I changed `-` to `_` and did some other renaming work, And it still doesn't find its match. I don't understand how it works... would you please help me fix this...?

Comment: That's because you ignored its warning of not being able to parse that inventory file; the `ansible-inventory -i inventory/mycluster/inventory.ini --list` command will help you see the warning and inventory parse failure in isolation

Comment: @mdaniel  Thank you, I changed my version! But I'm getting this new error : `fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check ''127.0.0.1' | ipaddr' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: no filter named 'ipaddr'. String: {% if '127.0.0.1' | ipaddr %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}"}`, even though I already installed python netaddr...

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error, and noticed that error does not exist in release-2.15(example), and node groups are written by "-", not by "_" initially. So if you don't care about release number, use 2.15. At least it helped me.

Comment: Thank you, I changed my version! But I'm getting this new error : `fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check ''127.0.0.1' | ipaddr' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: no filter named 'ipaddr'. String: {% if '127.0.0.1' | ipaddr %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}"}`, even though I already installed python netaddr...

Comment: Try using '127.0.0.1' | ansible.netcommon.ipaddr. Also Check out the [GitHub](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/68399) link for more information.